# What does '>/dev/null 2>&1' mean in this article of crontab basics?

Tags: cron

I am reading an article about [crontab](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

There is something about disabling automatically sending emails.

> 6. Disable Email By default cron jobs sends an email to the user account executing the cronjob. If this is not needed put the following
>      command At the end of the cron job line.
>
>    ```
>    >/dev/null 2>&1
>    ```

What is the detailed meaning for `2` `>` `&` and `1`? Why putting this to the end of a crontab file would turn off the email-sending thing?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

`>` is for redirect

`/dev/null` is a black hole where any data sent, will be discarded

`2` is the file descriptor for Standard Error

`>` is for redirect

`&` is the symbol for file descriptor (without it, the following `1` would be considered a filename)

`1` is the file descriptor for Standard Out

Therefore `>/dev/null 2>&1` redirects the output of your program to `/dev/null`.  Include both the `Standard Error` and `Standard Out`.

Much more information is available at The Linux Documentation Project's [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) page.

`cron` will only email you if there is some output from you job.  With everything redirected to `null`, there is no output and hence `cron` will not email you.

Comment: What if the command that I run in the crontab file do not output anything? For example something like `rm -rf /home/somename/a.txt`. In this case, I don't need to add that, right?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo That's correct. A mail is delivered only when there is output on stdout or stderr. That's why they suggest to redirect both to `/dev/null` in the article.

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: What about for starting sshd daemon in crontab.  Is it advisable to use `> /dev/null`?

Comment: why is fd symbol not required for 2?

Comment: @SudipBhandari - because there is no redirect symbol (`>`) before it and therefore, unlike the `1`, cannot be mistaken for a filename by the shell.

Comment: @garethTheRed And is working it only with `& > /dev/null`? As I read here `&>filename # Redirect both stdout and stderr to file "filename."`

Answer (score 56):

`/dev/null` is a device file that acts like a blackhole. Whatever that is written to it, get discarded or disappears. When you run a script that gives you an output and if we add a `> /dev/null 2>&1` at the end of the script, we are asking the script to write whatever that is generated from the script (both the  output and error messages) to `/dev/null`.

To break it up:

- `2` is the handle for standard error or `STDERR`
- `1` is the handle for standard output or `STDOUT`

`2>&1` is asking to direct all the `STDERR` as `STDOUT`, (ie. to treat all the error messages generated from the script as its standard output). Now we already have `> /dev/null` at the end of the script which means all the standard output (`STDOUT`) will be written to `/dev/null`. Since `STDERR` is now going to `STDOUT` (because of `2>&1`) both `STDERR` and `STDOUT` ends up in the blackhole `/dev/null`. In other words, the script is silenced.

By the way, you need to have a `>` in front of `/dev/null 2>&1`. It should be:

```
x * * * * /path/to/my/script > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: `2>&1` is run AFTER we redirect the script's O/P to `/dev/null`. So why does that also go to `/dev/null`? Also, when I do `script > /dev/null` why does only STDOUT go to /dev/null and not everything?

Comment: a) There is no sequence involved, all redirects are parsed and applied before executing the program, b) that's how the standard streams work - STDOUT and STDERR are separated for scripting, logging and analysis purposes. You may very well sometimes want to only suppress STDOUT and still receive a mail if something is sent to STDERR.

Comment: a) Yes. 2>&1 is run after the script. So, when the script runs, it writes the output (STDOUT) to /dev/null, then it sees 2>&1, so it writes the STDERR to STDOUT, which is /dev/null. That way both 2&1 (STDERR and STDOUT) ends up in /dev/null
b) Standard behaviour as explained by Niels in the above comment.

Answer (score 18):

This is standard I/O redirection.

There are always three default files open.

- stdin (0)
- stdout (1)
- stderr (2)

So in this example, the stdout (`1`) is being redirected to `/dev/null`.

The `null` device is a device file that discards all data written to it.

Then stderr is then being redirected into stdout (`2>&1`), therefore, both stdout and stderr will go to `/dev/null`

**So** placing this at the end of a crontab job will suppress all output and errors from the command.

**Reference**

[I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Answer (score 10):

From the manual *cron(8)*:

> When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of the crontab […].

So what your article suggests here is to produce no output, thus sending no mail.
Another way (more convenient?) to disable mail is to use the `-m off` option, i.e.

```
crond -m off
```

Now to the syntax: this is specific to the Bourne shell language (and its derivatives such as `bash`, `zsh`, and so on).

```
[n]>file

[n]>fd
```

will redirect to file descriptor `n` (or standard output if unspecified) to file descriptor `fd`.

A file descriptor can be a file name of the address of a stream. `&` is the address operator as in the C language.

Conventionally, file descriptor `1` is standard output (a.k.a. *stdout*) and file descriptor `2` is standard error (a.k.a. *stderr*). The chunk

```
>/dev/null
```

is redirecting stdout to /dev/null.

```
'2>&1'
```

is redirecting the error stream to the output stream, which has been redirected to /dev/null. As such, no output is produced and no mail is sent.

Warning: the order of redirection matters:

```
>/dev/null 2>&1
```

is not the same as

```
2>&1 >/dev/null
```

Try these two commands with a non-privileged user:

```
ls >/dev/null 2>&1
ls 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

Indeed, in the later case, file descriptor `2` is set to the current address of file descriptor ``1 (which is *stdout* at this very moment), and then the file descriptor `1` is redirected to `/dev/null`. File descriptor `2` is still redirected to *stdout*, no matter what happens to file descriptor `1`.

Answer (score 4):

Normally when `cron` executes a cronjob it sends the output of the command given in the cronjob to the user account executing the cronjob. So when your cronjob executes `uptime` for instance the output of `uptime` is sent to the user by email.

To be clear the standard output (`stdout`) of the command is meant.
Now, if you execute the command `uptime` in the cornjob as follows:

```
uptime >/dev/null 2>&1
```

- `2>&1` means a redirection of the chanel 2 (`stderr`) to the chanel 1 (`stdout`). Both outputs are now on the same chanel (`1`).
- `>/dev/null`: means that the standard output (and the standard error output) is sent to `/dev/null`. `/dev/null` is a special file:

> Data written to a null or zero special file is discarded.

So, you discard the output and cron has nothing to send.

Answer (score 1):

Redirection Bash's reference manual says:

> The operator [n]>&word is used [...] to duplicate output file descriptors
>   To redirect both stderr and stdout to file you should use the form
>   &>file
>   ....

briefly: all STDERR and STDOUT messages will be redirect to `/dev/null`

Comment: But cron does not necessary run Bash: the default is usually sh. In which case, &>file will fail directly from the crontab line, even before it gets to run your script (so even a shebang in the script will not have yet been invoked).