# Output of cron to file

Tags: linux, cron

I have a text file `topcommand.txt` which has a command as below:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/top -c | grep 'some process name' >> /home/abcd/topout.txt
```

When I invoke this using `crontab topcommand.txt`, file `topout.txt` gets created but it is an empty file.

Is there something wrong with my `top` command?

Comment: please change the `top -c` part of your line with `top -bn1` and see if it helps you. With `-c` option, you are toggling the last known state of operational mode and it might give you a different behavior every time.

Comment: Hi,changing top -c to top -bn1 did not help either.

Comment: The `'some process name'` part must not containe any `%` of course, unless escaped by backslash.

Comment: That's correct the process name does not contain %, below is the actual command that i used.   * * * * * echo $(date) +  /usr/bin/top -c  -d 5 -n 2|grep 'IIBD*' >> /home/n997736/IIBD_output.txt | AWK '{PRINT $0, "\n"}'

Comment: * * * * * echo $(date) +  /usr/bin/top -c  -d 5 -n 2|grep 'IIBD*' >> /home/abc/IIBD_output.txt

Comment: That was the actual command.

Comment: * * * * * /usr/bin/top -c  -d 5 -n 2  >> /home/n997736/IIBD_output.txt 2>&1
That command writes a warning message to the file -TERM environment variable not set.
When i do an echo for the variable i see the variable is set.********iibd1:~> echo $TERM
xterm

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/top -c | grep 'some process name' >> /home/abcd/topout.txt 2>&1
```

You can find some explanation here:

> http://www.unix.com/solaris/207049-help-what-does-2-1-do-crontab.html
>
> [What does '>/dev/null 2>&1' mean in this article of crontab basics?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163352/what-does-dev-null-21-mean-in-this-article-of-crontab-basics)