# Checking for the existence of multiple directories

Tags: shell-script, shell, files, directory, control-flow

I want to check for the existence of multiple directories, say, `dir1`, `dir2` and `dir3`, in the working directory.

I have the following

```
if [ -d "$PWD/dir1" ] && [ -d "$PWD/dir2" ] && [ -d "$PWD/dir3" ]; then
    echo True
else
    echo False
fi
```

But I suspect there is a more elegant way of doing this. Do not assume that there is a pattern in the names of the directories.

The goal is to check for the existence of a few directories and for the nonexistence of others.

I'm using Bash, but portable code is preferred.

Comment: “The goal is to check for the existence of a few directories and for the nonexistence of others.” Well, your example checks for existence of *all* listed directories. Can you elaborate on this part ?  Is it all listed or any listed  ? Do you need a check that passed values are in fact directories and not other types of files ?

Comment: You don't need the `$PWD`, by the way. `[ -d "$PWD/dir1"]` is equivalent to `[ -d "dir1" ]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already expect them to be directories and are just checking whether they all exist, you could use the exit code from the `ls` utility to determine whether one or more ["errors occurred"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html):

```
ls "$PWD/dir1" "$PWD/dir2" "$PWD/dir3" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo All there
```

I redirect the output and stderr to `/dev/null` in order to make it disappear, since we only care about the exit code from `ls`, not its output. Anything that's written to `/dev/null` disappears — it is not written to your terminal.

Comment: Can you help me understand this command? I know what file descriptors are. I know `1` is stdout, `2` is stderr and I know what redirecting is. I don't understand the significance of `/dev/null`, and I do not know how to parse the command.

Comment: @Elegance I added a little explanation. For more in-depth answers regarding /dev/null, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163352/what-does-dev-null-21-mean-in-this-article-of-crontab-basics and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438130/why-is-dev-null-a-file-why-isnt-its-function-implemented-as-a-simple-program

Comment: Still trying to figure out how the syntax works. I read that `&>filename` redirects both  stdout and stderr to `filename`. So couldn't the command be simplified (at least to me it is more simple) as `ls "$PWD/dir1" "$PWD/dir2" "$PWD/dir2" &>/dev/null && echo All there`?

Comment: It could, but not portably -- plain `sh` does not understand `&>`; it would misinterpret that as "run me in the background and send stdout to the redirection". I spelled it out from habit and kept it there because of the "portable code" preference.

Comment: Thank you very much, by the way. There's just one thing escaping me. `ls "$PWD/dir1" "$PWD/dir2" "$PWD/dir2" >/dev/null` This redirects the output to "nothing", right? Then, in my eyes, `2>&1` would take the the stderr (because of `2`) of nothing and redirect to stdout (because of `&1`) of god knows what. I understand what this is doing, I just don't get the syntax, it's not consistent with the regular use of `>`. I know I'm wrong in saying this, I'm just trying to explain what's on my mind. Should I ask this in another question? One last question: can it be adapted for nonexistence?

Comment: I redirected stdout for directories that exist and stderr for directories that don't exist -- we don't care about the contents of the former nor about `ls`'s complaints about the latter.  The redirections are processed in order, so after "dumping" stdout, stderr is then pointed to where stdout *now* points (the same /dev/null).  See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators

Comment: (1) You should probably use the `-d` option (a) so `ls` needs only to stat the directories, and not read them, and (b) so the command will succeed even if the user doesn’t have read access to the directories.  (2) I don’t see any reason to use ```"$PWD/"``` except to guard against directories whose names begin with `-` (and, of course, there are better ways to do that).

Comment: this command could take much longer to run than the test in the original question. also it doesn't check for directories.

Answer (score 12):

I would loop:

```
result=True
for dir in \
        "$PWD/dir1" \
        "$PWD/dir2" \
        "$PWD/dir3" 
do
    if ! [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        result=False
        break
    fi
done
echo "$result"
```

The `break` causes the loop to short-circuit, just like your chain of `&&`

Answer (score 6):

A loop might be more elegant:

```
arr=("$PWD/dir1" "$PWD/dir2" "$PWD/dir2")
for d in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [ -d "$d"]; then
        echo True
    else
        echo False
    fi
done
```

This is Bash. A more portable one is Sh. There you can use the positional array:

```
set -- "$PWD/dir1" "$PWD/dir2" "$PWD/dir2"
```

Then to loop over it use `"$@"`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just:

```
if [ -d "dir1" -a -d "dir2" -a -d "dir3" ]; then
    echo True
else
    echo False
fi
```

Comment: This is essentially what the OP started with, `But I suspect there is a more elegant way of doing this`

Comment: Also POSIX discourages the use of `-a`: "`-a` and `-o` binary primaries (...) operators have been marked obsolescent": http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: @JeffSchaller It's more terse since it does it all in one call to test.

Comment: @Elegance They're still supported on all the systems I use, and probably will be a hundred years from now.

Comment: it's not at all the same, the original invokes `test` (aka `[`) three times  this invokes it once,

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16 is a more precise reference to the location of the POSIX statement.

Comment: In view of @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' 's comment then it looks like `[-d "dir1" && -d "dir2" && -d "dir3"]` would be compliant without using the obsolescent `-a` but instead `shellcheck` tells me to split them as in the OP's original version.

Comment: @pbhj:  Obviously you didn't try that.   David Conrad's answer at least works; yours is wrong in a couple of ways.

Comment: I did try it (BASH, on Kubuntu) in the context of a different script (for my mopp-unofficial project on gitlab), but rewrote it by hand to match the question here. Like I said, `shellcheck` said splitting it was preferable - but not why, I didn't investigate - so I reverted to the split version which basically matches the original question.  As it was a comment I didn't check my syntax, that wasn't the point of the comment -- please explain my error.

Comment: fwiw, https://gist.github.com/pbhj/cd6bd6b83a1ccbaaf55b7f870e16b9d4 shows the shellcheck outputs in case anyone wants to follow up.

Answer (score 4):

As per the question, two portable shell functions that test for the existence and nonexistence of multiple directories:

```
# Returns success if all given arguments exists and are directories.
ck_dir_exists () {
    for dir do
        [ -d "$dir" ] || return 1
    done
}

# Returns success if none of the given arguments are existing directories.
ck_dir_notexists () {
    for dir do
        [ ! -d "$dir" ] || return 1
    done
}
```

Example:

```
$ mkdir dir1 dir2
```

```
$ ck_dir_exists dir1 dir2; echo $?
0
$ ck_dir_exists dir1 dir2 dir3; echo $?
1
```

```
$ ck_dir_notexists dir1 dir2 dir3; echo $?
1
$ ck_dir_notexists dir3 dir4; echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 1):

> The goal is to check for the existence of a few directories
>   ***and for the nonexistence of others.*** 
>   <sub>[Emphasis added]</sub>

Building on [glenn jackman’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503830/80216#503832),
we can test for the nonexistence of other names like this:

```
result=True
for dir in \
        "$PWD/dir1" \
        "$PWD/dir2" \
        "$PWD/dir3" 
do
    if ! [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        result=False
        break
    fi
done
for dir in \
        "$PWD/dir4" \
        "$PWD/dir5" \
        "$PWD/dir6" 
do
    if [ -e "$dir" ]; then                      # Note: no “!”
        result=False
        break
    fi
done
echo "$result"
```

I used `[ -e "$dir" ]` to test whether `"$dir"` exists;
i.e., if `dir5` exists but is a file, the result is `False`. 
If you want only to test whether the names in the second group are directories,
use `[ -d "$dir" ]`, like in the first loop.

Since we’re talking about checking for the existence of things
in the current working directory,
it’s probably not necessary to specify `$PWD/` on the names; just do

```
for dir in \
        "dir1" \
        "dir2" \
        "dir3" 
do
      ︙
```