# Please explain this shell script snippet with an rm command

Tags: bash, io-redirection, rm

I am a beginner to the unix scripts, can anyone please explain what does the below lines mean:

```
BTEQTEMPDELLOGS=$LOGS/${tablename}.DELlog

rm $BTEQTEMPDELLOGS 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
```

Comment: I'm curious about the reasons of downvoting. I'm not saying the question doesn't necessarily deserve it, but I think for a newbie proper feedback is helpful.

Comment: I suspect the downvote is for "This question does not show any research effort ..."

Comment: sorry evryone .its been few days i started researching , but i was not knowing about /dev/null .so thought of posting it

Comment: @chetangowda It becomes quite a different question if you had said it was `/dev/null` that was your issue, and not the `rm` or the variable assignment or something else.

Comment: In the crontab-related duplicate, look in particular at [the answer from the user called Sree](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163362/116858)

Answer (score 1):

The `rm` ("remove") command removes a file. The name of the file to be removed is given in a variable `BTEQTEMPDELLOGS`, instead of directly.  Any error messages (`2>`) by `rm` are sent to `/dev/null` (thrown away), the same for normal output (`1>`).

The variable `BTEQTEMPDELLOGS` itself is constructed in your first line by concatinating the variable `LOGS`, a literal '/' and the variable `tablename` with the string ".DELlog" at the end.

Here is documentation on (input and) output redirection: [GNU bash manual: Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

In your example, only output is redirected, not input.  `1>` redirects the normal messages issued by `rm` (there usually are none), `2>` redirects only the error messages (file not found etc.).

Here is more detailed information on these numbers ("file handles" from the programmer's point of view): [stdin (0), stdout (1) and stderr (2) in-/output of programs](http://www.learnlinux.org.za/courses/build/shell-scripting/ch01s04.html).

Here is documentation on `/dev/null`: [Wikipedia: NULL device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device)

Comment: Additionally, since the `$BTEQTEMPDELLOGS` value is used unquoted, it will be split on whitespaces (spaces, tabs and newline by default) and each generated word will undergo filename globbing if they contain filename globbing characters (such as `*` or `[` or `?`, or backslash (in recent versions of `bash`)) before `rm` is called to delete the file corresponding to each word.

Comment: Yes, an improvement of the code would be to use `rm "$BTEQTEMPDELLOGS" 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null`.

Comment: Or just `rm -- "$BTEQTEMPDELLOGS" 2>/dev/null`, as `rm` never generates output, and you'd want to protect the value from being interpreted as a set of options, just in case it (`$LOGS` really) starts with a dash.

Comment: @Kusalananda The variable seems to created by ourselves (lines above the snippet), not user input, so this might well be only a theoretical risk and may complicate discussion.

Comment: Possibly, but we don't actually know where `$LOGS` comes from.

Comment: thanks for the reply .its helps in understanding ..i got to know the snippet which i sent .but $LOGS is the variable which holds the the path where logs to be stored.. rm filename  2>/dev/null and 1>/dev/null , if errors are there then it removes but what about inputs.(1>/dev/null)

Comment: @chetangowda The input is not redirected. The `rm` command usually has no input (except when used interactively, e.g. `rm -i .......`).  I am adding more information on the distinction between `1>` and `2>`). If it helped please accept the answer.